# Adding filter on subgrid add button dropdown list

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a 1:N relationship from EntityA to EntityB, I have plopped a subgrid on the form of EntityA showing all related (1:N) EntityB records.

As usual, there is a "+" button for that subgrid, when clicking it, this shows a textbox with an hourglass to the right. When clicking the hourglass, a drop down deploys, showing all EntityB records. At the end of this list, there's a "New +" button, letting users add a new record.

Since this is a 1:N relationsip, adding an EntityB already linked to another EntityA throws an error saying the record is already associated.

Why is it then not filtering or preventing the ability to select other records then ?

If I can't configure the grid so that when the "+" icon is clicked, it goes straight to create form of EntityB, can I at least filter the dropdown so it shows no record at all and reduce likelyhood of users being confused by showing only the "New +" link ?

I know how to filter for simple lookup fields

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('new_field').addPreSearch(function () {
    Xrm.Page.getControl('new_field').addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
});
```

But for that dropdown list, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a 1:N relationship between `EntityA` and `EntityB` without the relationship field (look up) being a required field. This does not enforce relationship integrity, meaning you could have associations between records which do not have a related record.

Make the lookup field (to `Entity A`) on `EntityB` form a required field, which will automatically create a new record when `+` button is clicked.

Comment: That solved it, no need to try and filter that dropdown now, the "+" opens the create form right away!